# Merge (no branch) into master

Tags: git, version-control

```
dave@dave-dev:/media/dev/belgravia$ git branch
* (no branch)
  master
```

I'm not sure how this happened, but is there a way I can merge no-branch into the master. I'm not sure how I can merge two branches when one of them is not a branch. The commits in no-branch seem to be loose. I'm afraid that `checkout master` will cause data loss.

Comment: In my case, that just happened after a conflict during `git rebase`. Just do `git rebase --continue` and it bring you back to the branch you were on before.

Comment: also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366093/git-commit-against-tag-with-no-branch

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Use `git show` to get the SHA1 commit ID of the current HEAD. With that information, you can't lose those commits.

Then, switch to master and:

```
git merge abc123
```

where `abc123` is the SHA1 from the first step.

Comment: What I ended up doing was `branch temp`, `checkout master`, `merge temp`. That moved no branch into an actual branch, then I could merge it. Your solution is more simple however.

Comment: @Keyo: It didn't move "no branch" into a branch. It created a branch at your current HEAD (currently checked-out commit). When git branch said "no branch", it meant just that: you had no branch currently checked out. This is also known as detached HEAD.

Comment: Instead of git show, you can also use something like log --graph -20 --pretty=oneline - just to get the SHAs, but for the last 20 commits. Easier to check where you blundered, I think.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can commit it on current branch(no-branch)

Then you have to do:

```
git reflog
```

After that you can get the id of this commit like 1d84d08

do:

```
git checkout master 
git merge 1d84d08
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason you have (no branch) is you have done:

```
git checkout REMOTE_BRANCH_NAME
```

- In order for you to work locally on that branch you have to do: `git checkout -b local_branch_new_name`
- now do a: `git branch - a`
- you will see:

> local_branch_new_name
>
> ```
>   master
> ```

- From here you can merge a branch into master the usual way. switch to master and do:

  git merge local_branch_new_name